# Create Analytics from http using spark streaming

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Hi My reqmnt is to create Analytics from `http://10.3.9.34:9900/messages` that is pull data from from `http://10.3.9.34:9900/messages` and put this data in HDFS location `/user/cloudera/flume` and from HDFS create Analytics report using Tableau or HUE UI . I tried with below code at scala console of spark-shell of CDH5.5 but unable to fetch data from the http link

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
val dataRDD = sc.textFile("http://10.3.9.34:9900/messages")
dataRDD.collect().foreach(println)
dataRDD.count()
dataRDD.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/flume")
```

I get below error at scala console:

> java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: http at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2623)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2637)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:93) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2680)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2662) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:379) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a http endpoint as input, it needs to be a file system such as `HDFS`, `S3` or `local`.

You would need a separate process which is pulling data from this endpoint, perhaps using something like [Apache NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org/) to land the data on a filesystem where you can then use it as input to Spark.

Comment: Thank you , i was able to pull data from http socket using scala code,here is the code import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
val data = scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://10.3.9.34:9900/merged").mkString
val list = data.split("\n").filter(_ != "")
val rdds = sc.parallelize(list)
rdds.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/spark")